Sitecore Forms File uploaded in Media Library - Sitecore V10.3
We are using Sitecore Forms file upload functionality in forms. I need to know how to upload the files in Media library with user meta data .
If possible need to get the link of the file to send mail.

You can add the below method to your Submit Action
private List<string> UploadFileAndGenerateUrl(FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
{
    List<string> uploadedMediaURLs = new List<string>();
    var uploadFieldList = formSubmitContext.Fields.Where(f => f.GetType() == typeof(FileUploadViewModel));
    
    if (uploadFieldList != null && uploadFieldList.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var uploadField in uploadFieldList)
        {
            if (uploadField != null)
            {
                var uploadFieldVM = (FileUploadViewModel)uploadField;
                if (uploadFieldVM.Files != null && uploadFieldVM.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < uploadFieldVM.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var uploadFile = uploadFieldVM.Files[i];
                        uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;                                

                        var fileStream = uploadFile.InputStream; 
                        var fileName = uploadFile.FileName; 
                        if (fileStream != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                        {
                            var mediaCreator = new MediaCreator();
                            var options = new MediaCreatorOptions
                            {
                                Database = Sitecore.Context.Database,
                                Destination = $"/sitecore/media library/Form Uploads/{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)}",
                                FileBased = false,
                                IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
                                Versioned = false
                            };

                            var mediaItem = mediaCreator.CreateFromStream(fileStream, fileName, options);

                            // Optionally add user metadata
                            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
                            {
                                mediaItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                                mediaItem["Custom Metadata Field"] = "Your Metadata Value";
                                mediaItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                            }

                            uploadedMediaURLs.Add(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    return uploadedMediaURLs;
}
                            

In this code the media is uploaded to a folder called Form Uploads and you get the URL of the list of media files uploaded to file upload. You can use this list to send or embed it in the body of send email functionality.
Hope this helps !!!
